# Getting error: ORA-01858 in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting the error

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was
>   expected

```
select pia.vendor_id,
       pia.invoice_id,
       pia.invoice_date,
       pia.invoice_amount amount
from ap_invoices_all pia
where 1=1
  and (pia.invoice_date < to_date(&p_from_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') or &p_from_date is not null )
```

`invoice_date` is a DATE.

But if replace with:

```
pia.invoice_date < to_date('18/01/2015', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

is correct.

Why it's incorrect? And how to fixes?

Comment: Are you sure whatever value is entered in `p_from_date` is in the format `DD-MM-YYYY`? (You changed the date format in the example you gave where it worked).

Comment: Don't you want IS NULL instead in the where clause?

Comment: i forgor fomat string data type. i must be '&p_from_date' or input should be ' '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're missing the quotes around the substitution variables. Try this instead:

```
select pia.vendor_id,
       pia.invoice_id,
       pia.invoice_date,
       pia.invoice_amount amount
from ap_invoices_all pia
where 1=1
  and (pia.invoice_date < to_date('&p_from_date', 'DD-MM-YYYY') or '&p_from_date' is not null);
```

Comment: Thank you ! I forgot fomat string data type.